# Why can't I call my function created with the Function() constructor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using the Function Constructor inside a function to create functions when I'm calling it

Here is my constructor

```
funcGenerator(f) {
      return new Function(
        "value",
        "try{ return " + f + '; } catch (e) { return "error"; }'
      );
},
```

I call the function generator like this (inside an other function)

```
testFnc() {
    ... //content
}
```

And inside, I called the generator :

```
var myFnc = this.funcGenerator('value.toLowerCase()');
```

But now, when I'm trying to give it a parameter `value` like this

```
var textLow = myFnc('THIS to loWeR');
```

It didn't work. I tried to `console.log` to see if there's any problem and here are my results :

```
console.log(myFnc); //Display the function so this part works apparently
console.log(textLow); //Result is undefined
console.log(myFnc()); //Result is error
```

So apparently, my function is working but when I'm adding the `()` and try give it a parameter, It didn't work.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the code in one snippet (use toolbar to create snippet): that way we can reproduce what you describe.

Comment: So there's a `try ... catch ...` with a defined parameter for the `catch` and yet you only return "error" instead of the more useful error object in `e` (which might tell you the problem)

Comment: Show the actual code.... impossible for us to guess when you give us pieces that we have to randomly put together.

Comment: `funcGenerator = (f) => {
      return new Function(
        "value",
        "try{ return " + f + '; } catch (e) { return "error"; }'
      );
};
var myFnc = funcGenerator('value.toLowerCase()');
var textLow = myFnc('THIS to loWeR');
console.log(textLow);` works so I think you need to show more code so we can actually find the problem.

Comment: Dynamically building functions using strings is almost always a mistake, and there's usually another design that fits the need better, without incurring the security risks involved with allowing consumers to make up their own functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `myFnc()` in the last line of your code, you don't pass an argument, so `value` in undefined.

Yet you generated a function object that references `value`:

```
try{ return value.toLowerCase(); } catch (e) { return "error"; }
```

But `undefined` is not an object, so the reference to `toLowerCase()` triggers an error.

Comment: Ok, It was a typo problem... I solved it when I was writing a snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok with your code. You just need to pass a value to the function.
Instead of `console.log(myFnc()); //Result is error`
You should use

```
console.log(myFnc('Hello')); // Result is hello
```